# How to download deployed applications from Anypoint Platform?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have logged into Anypoint Platform -> Runtime manager where I can see all the mule applications running. How can I download that .zip file into my local machine such that can do modifications and deploy again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Applications - Click on the row with your CloudHub app -> on the right side a side bar appears.
It shows the status, the location and below a textbox and a "choose file" button.
You only have to click on the name that is displayed as a link in the textbox.

In my example below click you would click on "currency-convert-api-api-g...".

Hope that helps.

[image]

You should further think of CI / CD using either the Runtime Manager API or the Maven Plugin.

[MuleSoft Docs for Runtimer Manager API](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/runtime-manager-api)

[MuleSoft Docs for Maven Plugin](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

One can download the deployed file from the Anypoint Platform.

Login into Anypoint Platform.

Go to Runtime Manager

Click the area (near file name) as shown below in the image

[Deployed Application Name Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN9cr.png)

On the right side you will see the link to download the file. See the Image below

[Click for second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEGJ7.png)